# Connect 3 or more entities

Tags: erd

I'm new to data management. We are currently creating an ER diagram. First, I will ask a question and then give you an example.

#### Question

Can I connect 3 or more entities by one connection?

#### Task

Situation is university. We have groups, students, head of a group (I don't know what you call him. He is one of the students in group, and has certain duties. Each group has 1 head of a group).

Also we have classes, teachers and tasks. One teacher can have many classes and one class may be taught by many teachers.

Tasks are given to a certain group on a certain class by a certain teacher.

Not in diagram, in real world, teacher connected to a task and to a class. And these 3 objects can be presented as 1 object. And these connection of teacher, task and a class must be connected to group. That is what our teacher told us.

That sounds logical, but I can't think of a way to do that in ERD. What would you do?

Comment: This: **Tasks** are given to a certain **group** on a certain **class** by a certain **teacher**. The "Tasks" is what connects all the other three.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Well, it looks very logical, thank you a lot. I connected "Tasks" with "Group", "Class" and "Teacher". But I have entity "Student" which must be connected to "Group". Also I have entity "Progress". This entity contains "Student", date, grade and connected to "Tasks". Is it okay, that I connected "Students" with "Group" and with "Progress"?